# How to select an id from a xml element with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, visual-studio-2010, foreach

This is the XML what i'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <partners>
   <access>1</access>
   <partner>
      <accessPass></accessPass>
      <accessType>0</accessType>
      <updated>1</updated>
      <saved>0</saved>
      <fingerPrint>...</fingerPrint>
      <fpSent>0</fpSent>
      <fpLength>1</fpLength>
      <id>1234</id>
      <idAsign>123456789</idAsign>//----->This is the value i want
      <idCard>0</idCard>
      <name>..</name>
      <sku>531</sku>
      <status></status>
      <UserType>...</UserType>
   </partner>
....
</partners>
```

I want to select a specific value from an XML element, I have this method but I can't retrieve the single value I want.

```
 public XElement GetValueByID(string xmlPath, string value, string Segment, string child, string clause)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
        XElement partnerValues = (from el in xmlDoc.Elements(Segment).Elements(child)
                                             where el.Element(clause).Value == value
                                             select el).FirstOrDefault();
        return partnerValues;
    }
```

and in another class where i loop all "old list" to make the new list; this is how I get the value calling the method above:

```
XElement userID = methodsXML.GetValueByID(rootPath,item.IdPartnerCard,"partners","partner","id");
 if (userID != null){
    idAsig = int.Parse(userID.Element("idAsign").Value.ToString());

 }
```

by now this method return all the XML element then I have to select the item from the element in order to get the specific value, and it makes my program slow because I'm working with > 10k regs. Also I'm making a list to save a new XML with a foreach loop. I hope some one can help me with this issue.

thank you for your help.

Comment: What does your XML look like?  You're loading up and querying the document each time you call this method - how many times is it called?

Comment: And why are you passing in `rutaPart` when you're not actually using it? At the moment, your question is really pretty unclear.

Comment: Have you considered using XPath to query your XML document ? Depending on your query it might be much simpler to use

Comment: sorry i miss typed the "rutaPart" changing the variable name, And yes i'm loading the file each time it loops,I'ill fix it right now, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its easy just had to get the especific node and then get the value after calling the method who obtains the node in a XML format like `<idAsign>12345</idAsign>`

as follows

```
public XElement GetValuePartnerByID(string rutaPart, string id, string node)
    {
        XDocument archivoXML = XDocument.Load(rutaPart);

        XElement valuePart = (from c in archivoXML.Elements("partners").Elements("partner")
                                 where c.Element("id").Value == id
                                 select c.Element(node)).FirstOrDefault();
        return valuePart;
    }
```

and then

```
XElement userID = metodosXML.GetValuePartnerByID(path, item.IdPartnerCard, "idAsign");
                                    idAsig = int.Parse(userID.Value.ToString());
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

this works in LinqPad...

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(@"d:\test2.xml");
    XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable()); 
    GetElement(doc, "//partners/partner/idAsign", xnm).Dump();
}

public IEnumerable<XElement> GetElement(XDocument doc, string xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver res)
{
    return doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath, res);
}
```

Comment: How does this help the OP with the issue they're dealing with?  Simply dumping code with "Try this" is not an answer, IMO.

Comment: Sorry,  i'm not trying to make a list in the method, i just want to get a specific value each time i call the method which is in another class, ( i use this for 2 things, to know if it is in the XML file and to get the value). thank you for your answer ill see if i can use this.

Comment: @SKG - My point wasn't about my (or anyone else's) understanding of OP's issues in their code.  It was about posting code without some explanation of why the code would resolve the OP's issue.  That isn't really a good answer (IMO).   Remember, the answer you give may help another person with a similar issue down the road, and adding explanation will make it more valuable.  IMO, again.

Comment: @Tim..i understand your point...thanks...
How does your first take helps me identifying my issue "down the road" in resolving the problem? 
I atleast provided a workable solution like it or not...

I generally don't comment code that is self explaining....

Comment: @SKG - By "down the road", I meant if somebody months or years from now comes to Stack Overflow because they were doing a search on a similar issue, having an explanation of the code and why it applied to the original issue would be helpful, especially if the future reader's issue isn't quite the same.  And what you and I may consider self explaining may not be self-explaining to someone new to a language or a feature.

Comment: @SKG it says that `GetElement` does not exist in the current context o.o

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful:

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("partners.xml");
        XElement root = doc.Root;
        var id = from el in root.Elements("partner").Elements("idAsign") select el;


        foreach (var el in id)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(el.Value.ToString());
        }
```

I know this doesn't fit to your code (comboBox) but I wanted to show how to get values of the "idAsign" nodes.

Basically, what it does, it gets all the "idAsign" values. If you have them on a list, it's easy to get specific ones.